# Windows service and aspx

Tags: asp.net

1) I have a windows service which will download documents. Now it is saving correctly to textfile.

2) Class library which have load function and save function

3) Website for viewing the files  load and save to database.

For this In my windows service I have a reference to class library.

In my website I have reference to class library . But when I run my website "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" error is showing.
I am confused as the reference made is wrong or not.Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Code in Class library SerLib

```
    Public Function SavetoDB()

      dim X As String

     Dim obj As clsMRec 

     Try

     cmd =

    New SqlCommand

        cmd.Connection = con



    For Each obj In clsMCollect_mails



               cmd.CommandText =
```

"Insert into Master(From,,Subject) Values('" & mailRecObj.From & "',' " & mailRecObj.Sub & "',')"

```
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()         

          Next                

       Catch ex As Exception

        X = ex.Message()

     End Try

       End Function

      End Class
```

In the website

```
  Dim insMarec As New clsMaRec
' Dim c As p


Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    insMarec.SavetoDB()

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    insMarec.LoadfromServer()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**It seems there is not a problem with your reference**

System.OutOfMemoryException' It is thrown by the .NET Framework execution engine. It can occur during any allocation call during runtime.

**Example that raises out-of-memory exception: C#**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // This program attempts to create a string of 2.1 billion characters.
    // ... This results in an out-of-memory error.
    // ... It would require 4.2 billion bytes (4 gigabytes).
    string value = new string('a', int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

**Output**

**Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException.**

**Question**
**How much memory can be assumed?**

No specific amount of memory in bytes can be counted on when executing a program. For most programs that do not allocate huge amounts of memory, this is not a serious problem.

However:
If you have a problem with this exception and the cause is not obvious, you can use MemoryFailPoint to help diagnose the issue.

**So finally check again your code where you made any mistake like above example...
or Add some code in your qustion so we can understand batter ..**